# Как запустить последовательную команду терминала в PHP?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь запустить след последовательность:

```
$dir = '/usr/share/nginx/html/upload/';
exec("ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '".$dir."frame_*.jpg' ".$dir . 'frames.gif && rm -f '.$dir.'*.{jpg,png} > /dev/null &');
```

По логике команда должна быть послана, а код PHP завершен - без ожидания терминала. Так же после выполнение первой команды ffmpeg, должна выполниться вторая по удалению всех файлов с расширением jpg и png. 
Однако фактический результат в том, что выполняется только первая команда. А так же с добавлением второй команды (rm -f) как будто перестал работать **/dev/null &** и скрипт ожидает выполнение команды.
Подскажите что не так? Какие ошибки тут?

Comment: может потому что `rm` под `sudo` выполнять надо `и скрипт ожидает` - требует ввода пароля

Comment: возможно! потому что выполняя в терминале от рута, команда работает нормально.
А как тогда сделать правильно, чтобы удалить файлы?

Comment: Надо чтобы пользователю, под которым выполняется PHP скрипт, были даны права на удаление и работа с файлами, которые использует ffmpeg. Другими словами - дайте доступ на чтение вводных файлов и права на директорию и файлы для пользователя, чтобы он смог выполнять команды без sudo.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а как дать права на удаления для www-data только в конкретной папке (например /usr/share/nginx/html/upload) в Ubuntu не подскажите? 
p.s. Сама папка  /usr/share/nginx/html/upload имеет владельца "www-data" т.е. www-data имеет полный доступ к ней

Comment: Читайте документацию по UNIX правам (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в том то и дело, что у папки владелец www-data и все файлы и папки внутри /usr/share/nginx/html/upload создаются из php т.е. от www-data.

Comment: Проверьте под каким пользователем запускается PHP скрипт. Вы можете также попробовать запустить команду в консоли не как root, а как www-data (через su) и посмотреть на результаты/ошибки. Вообщем, делайте пошагово, и смотрите где и что работает или нет.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov запустил:
`$output2 = exec('rm -f /usr/share/nginx/html/upload/*.{jpg,png}',$output);`
var_dump($output) // выводит array(0) { }
var_dump($output2) // выводит string(0) ""
И ошибок нет и файлы не удаляет. Как так?

Comment: @alex70 если владелец файлов `www-data`, пусть PHP их и удаляет. `shell_exec('echo 123|sudo -u root -S|chmod -R 000 /var/www/mysite.com/test');` - `123` - пароль ROOT; `chmod -R 000 /var/www/mysite.com/test` - пример команды выполненной под `sudo`

Comment: @Guest удалить же их следует после выполнение команды конвертации, иначе конвертация выдаст ошибку из-за отсутствия файлов.Ну и запуск exec и есть запуск от www-data, так как файлы сделанные командой ffmpeg имеют владельца www-data. Значит все команды exec идут от www-data. Но почему не удаляются файлы непонятно, вроде все по логике верно.

Через рут запускать команды в PHP небезопасно, и тем более указывать пароли от рута в коде.

Comment: @alex70 то, что я выше писал - оно все равно от рута не работает (на рнр7), документация по вызову команды под судо - за 2009-2013 года - может раньше и работало, а щас в логе ошибок пишет, что ПУСТОЙ пароль - неправильный (не считывает STDIN консли), так как с точки зрения безопасности - это серьезная уязвимость, то может со временем и прикрыли эту "фичу"